# How to access subviews in View's initWithCoder method

Tags: ios, view, subview

I have a custom view which contains two UILabel. I want to customize their fonts before so I did that in initWithCoder method.

```
@implementation HomeTitleView
@synthesize ticketLabel;
@synthesize monthLabel;

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [monthLabel setFont:[UIFactory getFontForKey:@"home_month"]];
        [ticketLabel setFont:[UIFactory getFontForKey:@"home_ticket"]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Unluckily, this did not work. Using a debugger, I found that monthLabel and ticketLabel are both nil. Anyone has idea how can I solve this? What callback or method I should implement so that I can access both of my labels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that.  The views don't exist yet.  They are instantiated when the `loadView` method is called, which happens automatically when the `view` property is first accessed.  If you want to manipulate your views after they have loaded, the correct method to use is `viewDidLoad`.

**Edit:** That's assuming you are working with a `UIViewController` class.  If you are working with a `UIView` class, you can use `awakeFromNib` or `didAddSubview:`.

Comment: How can I do that? My customview extends UIView which doesn't have viewDidLoad callback. Or should I do in viewDidLoad of the view controller that I want to add this customview to?

Comment: Another possible solution for me that I can think of now is to create a custom UILabel class which I may be able to config the look and feel in it's init method... But I don't want to do that if possible :(

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were talking about a `UIViewController` subclass.  I've updated my answer to include information for `UIView` subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever assign monthLabel and ticketLabel to UILabel? Something like:

```
self.monthLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
self.ticketLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
```

If so, can you update your post with the code?

Comment: If the designated initialiser being called is `initWithCoder:`, then this means he's using a nib or storyboard - the views will be instantiated when the objects in that file are deserialised.